# Image urls in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, url, product-images, media

I have the following urls of an image

**original url**

http://www.trinca-ferro.com/media/product/7c2/ceramic-melon-knob-big-white-antique-finish-maria-e14.jpg

what is the /7c2/ , how it was generated?

how to  generate the cache url of the imaeg like below?

**cache url**

http://www.trinca-ferro.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/5/5/55550200-ceramic-melon-knob-big-white-antique-finish-maria_2_2.jpg

Comment: By default magento have this feature of serving images from cache for performance.

Comment: i'm generating sitemap using mirasvit extension , i want to change all the original url to cache url

Comment: means in sitemap, you want to display cache url?

Comment: yes , i need to display cache url

Comment: not sure, why you need cache url in sitemap. this is feature that mirasvit extension implemented that seo friendly product image url. if you want this to be done, try contacting mirasvit, for sure they will help you. if you need solution immediately you need to post the code that related to sitemap generation here. so that someone may help you here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.example.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/5/5/55550200-ceramic-melon-knob-big-white-antique-finish-maria_2_2.jpg

here

1. /1/ is store id
2. /9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/ is generated by magento default
   3./5/5/ -- first ans second letter of your image name used as directories for storing image

in the image name  55550200- added programmatic way